How do I add 3 data points to a calibration curve in R Studio?
I am trying to add data of a pre, post and control absorbance values to my calibration curve graph.
The code below is what I currently have, which creates a scattergraph and a line of best fit. However I need to plot the absorbance values of...
Control: 0.008
Pre-Treatment: 0.280
Post-Treatment: 0.117
...onto the graph using the line of best fit to find their concentrations. Here is my code below:
BSA <- data.frame(Concentration=c(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0), 
                 Absorbance=c(0.000, 0.182, 0.159, 0.121, 0.311, 0.352))

values <- data.frame(Sample=c("Control", "Pre-treatment", "Post-treatment"), 
                    Absorbance=c(0.008, 0.280, 0.117))

plot(BSA, ylab="Absorbance of BSA", xlab="Assay Concentration (ml/mg)", las=1) 
abline(lm(BSA$Absorbance ~ BSA$Concentration))


I am struggling to find a method to do this and previous posts are very specific to the user's data set and do not work with my data for some reason.

Not really following here.Looks like you fit a model  for absorbance as the dependent variable and concentration as the independent variable.  In your values dataframe, you only have absorbance (i.e. the outcome).  Should you be predicting concentration from absorbance instead?

@DemetriPananos Yes that is correct, I am trying to find the concentration of the Pre, Post and control samples from their absorbance values by plotting them on this graph, as I need to calculate their concentrations. I need to plot only these absorbance values on the line of best fit (which I am struggling to do) to predict the concentrations. Sorry for the confusion in my wording, very stressed student here right now haha!

I'm still not entirely clear on what you need, but it sounds like you need to:

Fit a model to predict concentration from absorbance
Predict concentration for some new values, and
Plot those predictions on the same plot.

Here is how I would approach it
# You provided...
BSA = data.frame(Concentration = c(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0), 
                 Absorbance = c(0.000, 0.182, 0.159, 0.121, 0.311, 0.352))

values = data.frame(Sample = c("Control", "Pre-treatment", "Post-treatment"),
                    Absorbance = c(0.008, 0.280, 0.117))


# Here is how I would do this...

# First, make a model
fit <- lm(Concentration ~ Absorbance, data=BSA)

# Next, plot your data
with(BSA, plot(Absorbance, Concentration))
# Add the line of best fit
abline(fit)

# Now, get the predictions from your "values" dataframe
predicted_concentration <- predict(fit, newdata = values)
values$predicted_concentration <- predicted_concentration

# Add the predictions to your plot, maybe in a different color

with(values, points(Absorbance, predicted_concentration, col='red'))


I'm not clear on what control/pre/post treatment mean here, maybe you can clarify if I've missed something.

This is perfect! Thank you, the pre-, post- and control are the absorbance values recorded for an experiment I conducted on whether a drug is effective in reducing protein concentration in urine (pre is before treatment, post is after treatment and control is a healthy individual), hence why I needed to find the relevent concentrations. Is there anyway from this I could find the exact value of concentrations of each red point on the graph? Thank you a lot for your help and sorry for my terrible explainations :)
